# Installed ubuntu with erase disk and cant boot. no grub

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

tried boot-repair. URL from that is:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14673632

thanks

Comment: HP only likes to use description to boot. And description must be Windows. But since you do not have Windows change/make description of grub2's shim file be "Windows". Run this from live installer:  `sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi" ` Then Boot Windows entry that is shim, not Windows files. Boot-Repair also copied shim to bootx64.efi which is a fallback or hard drive entry. I do not see that but UEFI may add it. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the GRUB boot loader this way :
Boot from Ubuntu installation media.
Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Note : `sda` = disk | `sda1` = EFI partition | `sda2` = system partition

In case Ubuntu still does not boot - maybe you have to select Ubuntu as default system in BIOS, because there still is Windows boot loader (Microsoft folder) installed on the EFI partition sda1.